# Is there any way to control RAM that Ruby's Thin server uses?

Tags: ruby, vps, thin

I have VPS with 1GB of RAM. One ruby-app that runs on thin server takes about 60+ MB of RAM, no matter if application is used right now or not. Is there any way to control this? Because right now Im runnin' out of memory. Any suggestions are accepted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 60+ like what? I mean, seriously - 60mb is around 6% of available memory. That would not really be an issue. OTOH, 900mb is also more than 60mb ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some monitoring tool to restart your thin when they use too much RAM

- [bluepill](http://github.com/arya/bluepill)
- [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)
- [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/)